# Page/BlocBuilder rebuilds on navigation return but there is no event in the logs

Tags: flutter, bloc

The situation is the following: I have 5 blocks on one page and each one returns a widget, however, when navigating to a new page (even if it is empty Scaffold () and I definitely don’t update any block there!), And returning back, the blocks start to rebuild (and not only blocks but also widgets are static on the same level with the block). When I comment out the problem block, the problem disappears in this case and none of the blocks are rebuilt. I write print, log(msg, name: 'Bug') but those events are not fired.

The problem block is quite standard. I try the navigation template Navigation ... -> the reaction is the same.

flutter_bloc: ^8.1.2 (also tried earlier version)

request:
`BlocProvider<RestaurantsCubit>( create: (_) => sl<RestaurantsCubit>()..getRestaurants(), ),`

request method:

```
void getRestaurants() async {
     emit(state.copyWith(status: CubitStatus.loading));
     final failureOrRestaurants = await fetchRestaurants(
       FetchRestaurantsParams(),
     );
     failureOrRestaurants.fold(
         (l) => emit(state.copyWith(
               status: CubitStatus.error,
               message: l.message,
             )), (r)async {
       emit(state.copyWith(
         status: CubitStatus.success,
         restaurants: r,
       ));
     });
   }
```

listener:

```
Column(children: [
  BlocBuilder(retun: AnyButton(navigate ... ))... //rebuild too
  Row( child: AnyButton(navigate ... )) // rebuild too

  BlocBuilder<RestaurantsCubit, RestaurantsState>(
    builder: (context, state) {
     print('HEY! ! ! I REBUILDED! - ${state.status}');
      if (state.status.isLoading) {
          return CustomShimmerWidget(width: 156.w, height: 100.h);}
      if (state.status.isSuccess) {
          r.eturn state.restaurants.isEmpty
              ? Text('empty(')
              : Listview(...) });

  BlocBuilder.. // rebuild too
```

I expect that the state of the page after the return should not be updated. Usually the guys can’t update, but on the contrary

Comment: I don't know how to delete my post here. But in general, I found the problem and fixed it. The problem was not with blocks but with the imageUrl display child widget. In my case there was a CachedNetworkImage but neither FadeInImage.network nor Image.network helped. The problem was that when returning from B-page(Navigator.pop()) -> A-page CachedNetworkImage restarted, but there were oddities in neighboring widgets that were rebuild. For me, this mystery remains because of what. I solved the problem by the fact that the imageUrl was of a large format, I replaced it with a smaller

Comment: If you think this information is useful for other people, feel free to write an answer to your own question describing what fixed the problem. If you really want to delete your question, there should be a button below your question body/above the comments (next to the `Edit` button) for doing so.